Adding ImageView Dynamically Behind Transparent Areas in Multiple Frames in Android App kotlin
I am developing an app where each frame contains a transparent area where users can place their images. The size and position of this transparent area vary across more than 100 frames, some having 3 image slots and others 4. I want to dynamically place an ImageView behind the transparent area so that I can avoid creating separate layouts for each frame. However, I'm unsure how to programmatically add an ImageView in the transparent area. An example of the frames can be seen here.
I want to dynamically place an ImageView behind the transparent area so that I can avoid creating separate layouts for each frame

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some code snippets showing what you have tried so far, where did you get stuck the most, etc., to help others help you.
